How to delete remaining podman containers on Windows11?

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!
STOP FLAGGING IT AS SUCH, IF YOU DIDN'T EVEN READ THE QUESTION!
NUMEROUS TOOLS SHOW THERE IS NO HANDLE LOCKING THE FILE BUT I CANNOT DELETE THE FILE ANYWAY. THAT IS THE PROBLEM.
I TRIED EVERY SOLUTION FROM THE OTHER POST, AND YOU GUYS STILL KEEP DOWNVOTING MY QUESTION. THIS IS COMEDY!️

Podmans leftovers use up quite a lot of my diskspace and I uninstalled podman desktop a few months ago. How do I remove those?

I tried it by simply deleting via rightclick in the context menu. Does not work.

I did wsl --unregister podman-machine-default
then I ran wsl --shutdown
Tried deleting it again. Same result. Doesn't work.
I tried it with powershell. Didn't work.
Restarted my pc and tried it again. Didn't work.
I really need that diskspace, because a lot of my programs store junk on my system drive and not on the drive they are installed on...
More context as music2myear suggested:
The message basically says, that I cannot delete the file, because some process uses it.
I tried checking which process is blocking me from deleting the file with this command: openfiles /query /fo table | find /I "C:\Users\jfroe\.local\share\containers\podman\machine\wsl\wsldist\podman-machine-default\ext4.vhdx" from a comment in the response that was marked as answer on the other post. I also tried handle.exe from the sysinternals suite before that, and both commands do not list any processes that lock the file. I also tried the powershell script, marked as the answer. Nothing logged any process.
The most upvoted answer (using the process explorer) also shows that no processes are blocking the virtual volume:


This question is similar to: Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@music2myear The problem is, that no command shows any processes that are locking the file. That is why the message is so weird.

@music2myear Please just read, what I wrote, before asking questions, I already answered.

@music2myear Somebody just deleted my response to your comment. I am honestly sick of this power abuse. I did write that and I even added a screenshot, as you can see.

@music2myear Why can you not admit, that you didn't read the full post? Your comments have many likes and that most probably had a great impact on the dowvotes I received! I was not being rude. I just pointed out the facts.

I don't know what fixed it, because I did try nothing more than what I explained in the post, but I restarted my PC a few times since the post and I guess that Windows fixed the issue by itself.
I was able to delete the file this time (I tried that after every restart, and i restarted my PC after every approach i tried (that are a lot of reboots), but this time it surprisingly worked).
Maybe this helps someone (that is the powershell script I ran (see "I tried it with powershell.")):
# Unregister podman wsl
wsl --unregister podman-machine-default
# Stop any running WSL instances
wsl --shutdown
# Take ownership of the directory
takeown /F "$env:USERPROFILE\.local\share\containers\podman" /R
# Grant full control permissions
icacls "$env:USERPROFILE\.local\share\containers\podman" /grant "$($env:USERNAME):F" /T
# Try to remove the directory (hopefully works, it did not for me, but it might work for you)
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "$env:USERPROFILE\.local\share\containers\podman"

I hope this helps someone.
And if no approach works, like it was for me, then just wait, maybe your OS fixes the problem for you.
What was also not deleted by the podman uninstaller (more than 250MB in my case) (maybe there is even more):
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\podman-desktop-updater"

You could also delete this, if you want to remove configurations too:
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Podman Desktop"
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "$env:USERPROFILE\.config\containers\podman"

